# Calabash iOS how to tap the back button item

Tags: ios, calabash, calabash-ios

Guys just cant figure out how to tap on BackButtonItem from Navigation Bar with Calabash framework, I'm setting accessibilityLabel like this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.accessibilityLabel = "goBack"
```

and trying to test it like this with no luck:

```
touch("* marked:'goBack'")
touch_transition('navigationItemButtonView first',
                       "* marked:'#{goBack}'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend trying `query "all * marked:'goBack'"` and if that still doesn't return any results, just try a `query "all *"` and see if the label shows up in the results.

You could also try setting the `accessibilityIdentifier` of the view - generally that's the preferred way to set up views for automation.

Comment: OP code is valid Swift code. Yours is exactly the same in Objective-C language.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that UINavigationItem, UITabBarItem, and UIToobarItem are converted, at runtime, to Views.  For example, a UITabBarItem is converted to a UIToobarButton.  In the conversion, the accessibilityIdentifier and accessibilityLabel are not preserved.

```
# This will probably get you the left navbar button
query("UINavigationItemButtonView index:0")
```

There are ways to enforce that an accessibilityIdentifier is preserved, such as making the navigation item from a custom view.

Take a look at the [briar bars/navbar.rb](https://github.com/jmoody/briar/blob/develop/lib/briar/bars/navbar.rb) for inspiration.  I do not recommend using briar in your project; its life is uncertain (I am the maintainer).

Comment: Updated to fix errors and added a link to sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating it might be helpful for someone who wish to use default back button 
`touch('navigationItemButtonView first')`

This will take you back.
Found from calabash predefined steps.